# Are we using the criticism tag correctly?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, critique

The [criticism](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism) description says it's for:

> Questions dealing with writing criticism, and with receiving criticism from others.

The wiki adds:

> Questions to do with:
>   - How to write criticism (e.g. movie reviews)
>   - How to interpret and respond to criticism of one's work
>   - How to obtain constructive criticism
>   ...and any other questions pertaining to writing criticism and receiving it for others.
>
> Please distinguish from the critique tag, which is for requesting critiques for particular pieces of work.

The "critique" tag no longer exists.  However, some critique questions are now being tagged [criticism](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criticism).

Is the wiki correct?  If so, some questions should be detagged.  If not, it should be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO we should do what the tag wiki says and remove that tag from questions that *ask for critiques* as opposed to *asking how to do critiques*.

(After discussions here and in chat, this has been implemented.)

Comment: Agreed. I point you at the meta question: [Is critique a meta-tag?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/495/is-critique-a-meta-tag) The tag was [subsequently burninated](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/560/can-the-critique-tag-be-burninated-please).

Comment: I've updated the tag wiki for now. If there's general agreement, the mods can do a mass edit to remove the tag from critique questions.

Comment: @NeilFein good edit.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd further suggest we change the name of the [tag:criticism] tag to something that's clearer, but I can't think of anything. Something that means "the process of giving or receiving criticism".

Comment: Thanks for raising this @MonicaCellio. I am afraid I have been guilty of wrongly tagging a couple (or maybe one) of questions with the criticism tag too. Shall we start correcting?

Comment: @PraveshParekh community maintenance of a tag set is hard; you may not have been the first, and if not you were just following suit.  The purpose of this question is to clarify our position, after which we'll act.  I think we're going to end up removing it from those questions, but we may as well do those as one batch once we decide, instead of tackling them one at a time.

Comment: @NeilFein: Umm...critical-analysis (might overlap with critique), critical-writing (not really), critical-appraisal (don't think so), critical-process (has a different meaning), critical-method (nay), criticism-method (blah)...nope. No good. Anything on your mind?

Comment: Questions retagged.